# Is there a way to call the onkeypress event after a second so that it wouldn't fire a method a bunch of times?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I'm writing a program that calls a method which shows data on a table using a textbox. The problem is that it calls the program more than 10 times each time. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's the text box:

```
<input #input matInput placeholder="Search data" (keyup)="onKeypressEvent($event)">
```

Here's the method I'm calling:

```
  onKeypressEvent(event: any){
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,'keyup')
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(150),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            tap(() => {
                this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
                this.loadData();
            })
        )
        .subscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because on every key press you create a new chain so `debounceTime()` has nothing to debounce. Instead make a Subject and push key presses. Then make just one subscription in constructor or in onInit():

```
keyPress$ = new Subject();

...

keyPress$.pipe(
  debounceTime(150),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  tap(() => {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    this.loadData();
  }),
).subscribe();

...

onKeypressEvent(event: any) {
  this.keyPress$.next(event);
});
```

Comment: You may move the `tap` code to the `subscribe` method. Same result, but easier to read I guess

Comment: @martin is there a reason why the data loads slower or is it because of debounce time?

Comment: @kajl16 That's what `debounceTime` does. Maybe have a look at `auditTime` and `sampleTime` and `throttleTime`

Answer (score 0):

As per your existing code, it looks like you are using `@viewChild()`.

Here is the simple & working solution. This avoids the additional `Subject` to use.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, "keyup")
      .pipe(debounceTime(1000)) // Update the debouceTime as per your wish
      .subscribe((val: KeyboardEvent) => {
        console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
      });
  }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe it on `onDestroy`.